# Scraping a web Page in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping

I need to scrape the content of the page:
https://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/GBTC/security

in a Google spreadsheet, so that I can further elaborate that.

I failed miserably,
can you help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scrape a web page in Google Sheets, you might benefit from making use of one of the formulae below:

- `IMPORTHTML` which is used to import data from a table or list within an HTML page;
- `IMPORTXML` which is used to import data from any of various structured data types including XML, HTML, CSV, TSV, and RSS and ATOM XML feeds.

However, if the content you want to retrieve is dynamic, you might need to look for other alternatives as **both** of these commands read the `HTML` source of the page without any JavaScript code associated with it and **without** executing it.

#### Reference

- [Google Sheets IMPORTHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en);
- [Google Sheets IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en).